# Is it possible to have a form in ms-access get "signed" by a stylus as an entry? If so, how?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm developing a ms-access database to remove the need for paper versions of toolbox meetings. End of the day I want to put this database on a windows tablet and have the work crew sign a form on it using their finger/stylus. The form and tables are created however I have no idea how to make a signature part of it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to save a signature for each person as image objects in database. Then users input an encrypted authorization code as their 'e-signature'. Report displays the appropriate signature image when the authorization code is in the record.

Otherwise, Google: capture signature in access database

Here is one [Capture signature into database](https://www.microsoftaccessexpert.com/Microsoft-Access-Signature-Capture-Database.aspx)

Saving each and every original signature into Access db could chew up the 2gb file size limit if saved as images. Whether saved as images or vector coordinates, I expect the code would be complex.

Comment: One approach is to save a signature for each person as image objects in database. Then users input an encrypted authorization code as their 'e-signature'. Report displays the appropriate signature image when the authorization code is in the record.

This is a great way to ensure the signing of forms isn't misused, I ended up using Microsoft InkPicture Control to finalise my form, however security isn't important for my use.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Microsoft InkPicture Control. You can Google for examples.